# Tags JSF não estão sendo convertidas em HTML

Tags: java, jsf, maven, tomcat

Criei um projeto Maven no Eclipse para usar JSF e fiz todas as configurações que o material pediu. Porém, quando criei um arquivo XHTML e rodei no navegador, o código-fonte da página não foi convertido para HTML comum, ou seja, continuava com as tags JSF.

**oi.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Teste inicial JSF</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputText value="Olá Mundo" />
</h:body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <display-name>teste</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Fase de desenvolvimento do projeto (Production, Development, UnitTest, 
        SystemTest, Extension) -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Campos de formulário que forem submetidos em branco são recebidos como 
        null -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Campos de data e hora utilizam o fuso horário definido no sistema -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Arquivos que serão exibidos (em ordem de prioridade) caso o endereço 
        requisitado não especifique um arquivo diretamente -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.pro.fagnerlima</groupId>
    <artifactId>teste</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Teste</name>
    <description>Primeiro projeto com JSF</description>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Java 1.8 -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- UTF-8 -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jvnet-nexus-releases</id>
            <name>jvnet-nexus-releases</name>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- JSF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altere seu web.xml de:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Altere para:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Você definiu arquivos `.jsf` mas você criou com `.xhtml`.

Comment: Tem alguma forma de usar as duas extensões?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que assim você consiga utilizar os dois:

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```